# Bubble chart connected by entity in PowerBI

Tags: excel, charts, powerbi, bubble-chart

It seems like this question has been asked for other languages but PowerBI seems like a good way to visualize the data I have. I have the data in an excel spreadsheet currently.

I am familiar with bubble charts in POWERBI but what I wanted to do was to use that idea further and connect the bubbles based on criteria.  So have a company in the middle with other companies connected based on their relationships. The size of the bubble would correspond to how much of the specific criteria the company contributed. I have attached an image for convenience.

Apologies if this can be done with ease.

Thanks,
 [image: Image showing what I want to achieve]

Comment: I would check out this visual in the Microsoft Office Store: [link](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104380795&sourcecorrid=14553136-0bf8-4ce6-93b9-9cd9a7459eff&searchapppos=13&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&appredirect=false)

Comment: @JohnFriel awesome thanks John!